# "du" command on Windows10 under MSYS2 gives "fts_read failed" error on USB formatted as exFAT/FAT32

Tags: usb, filesystems, du, msys2

I'm currently using MSYS2 on Windows10 and I tried to execute `du` in the MINGW64 Shell Launcher on a USB formatted as exFAT.
Assuming the USB is mounted on `/g/`, the structure of the USB is pretty much like this:

```
/g/$Thesis/
/g/Giochi/
/g/PROGRAMMING/
/g/System Volume Information/
/g/Video/
/g/_$CR/
/g/test/
```

When I execute `du -sh /g/*` this is what I get:

```
0       /g/$Thesis
du: fts_read failed: /g/Giochi/Lobotomy-Corp/Saves/Sav1/Lobotomy/Unity: No such file or directory
6.6M    /g/PROGRAMMING
8.0K    /g/System Volume Information
0       /g/Video
0       /g/_$Cr
20K     /g/test
```

The structure of the problematic folder `Giochi/Lobotomy-Corp/Saves/Sav1/Lobotomy/Unity/` is something like this:

```
...
Lobotomy/
|...
|--Unity/
   |--local.775c7d8c8116fb84a9c9bb47890hg7a8/
      |--Analytics/
         |--config
         |--values
         |--ArchivedEvents/
            |--879942335000001.1sa7f78b/
               |--e
               |--g
               |--h
```

I copied all the files from this USB to a new USB. Assuming this new USB is mounted on `/h/`, this is what I tried to do:

- I formatted the new USB as exFAT, executed `du -sh /h/*` but the error was the same on that particular folder
- I formatted the new USB as FAT32, executed `du -sh /h/*` but the error was the same on that particular folder
- I tried `du -sh` on the same files but on my Desktop that is formatted as NTFS and it worked:

  ```
  0       /old-USB-files/$Thesis
  429K    /old-USB-files/Giochi/    
  6.6M    /old-USB-files/PROGRAMMING
  2.0K    /old-USB-files/System Volume Information
  0       /old-USB-files/Video
  0       /old-USB-files/_$Cr
  5.0K    /old-USB-files/test
  ```
- I formatted the new USB as NTFS, executed `du -sh /h/*` and it worked

Then I started to make some tests on the new USB formatted as exFAT/FAT32 by copying specific files:

- I copied **only** the `Unity` folder, executed `du -sh /h/Unity` and it worked
- I copied **only** the `Lobotomy` folder and executing
     `du -sh /h/Lobotomy` gave the error but
     `du -sh /h/Lobotomy/` gave the right output with no errors

Could the `du` command on MSYS2 be the problem ?
There's something wrong about `du` on exFAT/FAT32 filesystems in general or on USB formatted like that ?

**EDIT:**

I recently installed WSL1 with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my machine.
I formatted the new USB as exFAT, copied the files, created a mount point `/mnt/h` and mounted the new USB with

`sudo mount -t drvfs H: /mnt/h`

Then I ran `du -sh /mnt/h` and it worked with no problem whatsoever.
Could MSYS2 actually be the problem ?

Comment: Check the flash drive for file system errors (`chkdsk`).

Comment: I checked the old USB and the new one but no error were found.